# Where did Account Bound item come from

Tags: diablo-iii

While in the Sell window of the Gold Auction House, I noticed an item in my stash, which appeared in red and could not be sold. It was amongst some other items, which I received in-game from another player. I did recently re-arrange items in my stash, so it could have been moved from elsewhere in the stash.

When I looked at the item in-game, it appeared as an "Account Bound" item. This means that it was crafted by me sometime? Could the other player have given me an Account Bound item? He just dropped items on the ground for me to pick up -- we didn't trade them officially.

Comment: If it's an account bound item, there's no way it came from another character.  What is it?

Comment: Rare Shoulders, level 60.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the other player couldn't give you an *Account Bound* item. Neither could you pick up somebody else's *Account Bound* item.

There are 4 ways you could have one of them:

- You crafted it ([Hellfire Rings](http://www.diablowiki.net/Hellfire_ring), Shoulders, Amulets, Bracers, [Marquise](http://www.diablowiki.net/Marquise_gem) gems, Portal Devices, etc.)
- You inserted a [Marquise](http://www.diablowiki.net/Marquise_gem) gem into an item that made it *Account bound* due to the gem. If you will remove the gem, this item will become normal again(unless it was crafted as in the first point)
- You found it from some monster(Keys, blacksmith plan for *Portal Device*, various ingredients for [Staff of Herding](http://www.diablowiki.net/Staff_of_Herding))
- You bought it from an NPC(bell for [Staff of Herding](http://www.diablowiki.net/Staff_of_Herding), blacksmith recipes for various difficulties of [Staff of Herding](http://www.diablowiki.net/Staff_of_Herding), blacksmith recipe for [Hellfire Ring](http://www.diablowiki.net/Hellfire_ring), etc.)

Hope it helps

***EDIT***

Totally forgot about one more way to get an *Account Bound* item. If you have a special version of the game(Collectors Edition for example), you will be granted 3 *Account Bound* items:

- [Angelic Wings](http://www.diablowiki.net/Angelic_Wings)
- [Bottled Cloud](http://diablonut.incgamers.com/item/bottled-cloud)
- [Bottled Smoke](http://diablonut.incgamers.com/item/bottled-smoke)

It seems like you can also get some exclusive items by registering special versions of other [Blizzard](http://www.blizzard.com) games, but I do not have any information about it

Answer (score 1):

Blizzard may also bind items to your account if someone reports an account was hacked and Blizzard does a rollback.

If you haven't logged in for a while, they were binding items on account during the gold dupe incident.

Comment: Not to say that either of those is the explanation. With shoulders, the most likely explanation is that you crafted them. See http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/archon-spaulders -- is that them?

Comment: Yes, those are them. I don't think the other explanations are applicable though.